# Colorize transparent part of SVG icons

Tags: css, svg, font-awesome, tailwind-css

I want to colorize a transparent part of a svg icon from font awesome. I am using Vue Fort-Awesome package.

Here as you see inner part of icon is getting the background image of my main div. However I don't want those part to be transparent. Do you have any tricky solution for it? I know this question can be very easy but I couldn't find how to search for it on google.

[image]

```
<v-icon
  icon="minus-circle"
  class="w-6 h-6 rounded-full text-red-500"
/>
```

Those are technologies that I use but simple css trick can be acceptable too.

Tailwind 
Vue3 
FortAwesome

Comment: Have you tried adding a background color to the icon? Like `class="w-6 h-6 rounded-full text-red-500 bg-white"`

Answer (score 0):

You can change the color of the minus or circle by changing the hex value in the `fill` section.
For other icons, you can change color by editing the svg file.

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" fill="#00970F"/>
<rect x="39" y="88" width="123" height="25" rx="10" fill="#FA00FF"/>
</svg>
```